# Pyomo Set multi-level indexing

Tags: python, pyomo

In a production and transportation problem I am trying to model using Pyomo, I want to 1) assign each product a separate time duration with a specific starting point, and 2) activate an operating rule for each product within its own time duration.

I define a 2-dim array `model.Tpp` of type `Set` in an AbstractModel,

```
def tpp_rule(model,p):
    return range(value(model.G[p]),value(model.T))
model.Tpp = Set(model.Prod, initialize=tpp_rule, ordered=True)
```

Here, `model.G[p]` specifies the starting point for each product in `model.Prod` indexed by `p`.

It is well defined, but error is returned when I call this two 2-dim array,

```
def operation_rule(model, t, p):
    return (1)  ## rule is simplified here
model.Operation3 = Constraint((model.Tpp[p] for p in model.Prod), model.Prod, rule=operation_rule)
```

The error shows,

```
RuntimeError: Cannot iterate over abstract RangeSet 'Prod' before it has been constructed (initialized).
```

Would someone please suggest me how I should call the 2-dim array, or even what is the proper way to define it?

Comment: first of all, I dont think you can index a constraint with `model.Tpp[p] for p in model.Prod` instead just index it with `model.Tpp`. A const would loop through all indices of model.Tpp if you declare it right. I am going to give you an example soon...

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an example:

> Be aware my model is a concrete model. For abstract ones I guess you should
>   give the elements or values into your .dat file?

Assume I got a site set which shows all of the sites and a pro set, which shows all of the process -are available-. OFC you need to change the `initialize` part, since you do not have any of my dataframe(data).

```
m.sit = pyomo.Set(
    initialize=data['site'].index.get_level_values(0).unique())

m.pro = pyomo.Set(
    initialize=m.process.index.get_level_values('Process').unique())
```

Which looks like this: (Red ones are the elements of the sets sit and pro)

```
(Pdb) master.sit.pprint()
sit : Set of sites
    Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    ['Mid', 'North', 'South']
(Pdb) master.pro.pprint()
pro : Set of conversion processes
    Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=8, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    ['Biomass plant', 'Coal plant', 'Gas plant', 'Hydro plant', 'Lignite plant', 'Photovoltaics', 'Slack powerplant', 'Wind park']
```

Now I want to merge them into a tuple, which would have all the elements of sit and pro together.

```
m.pro_tuples = pyomo.Set(
    within=m.sit*m.pro,
    initialize=m.process.index.remove_unused_levels())
```

OFC you need to change init. part. But rest is how you declare a tuple(m.sit*m.pro), then you can give a constraint pro_tuples as index, and then you would get your multi-level index.

```
(Pdb) master.pro_tuples.pprint()
pro_tuples : Combinations of possible processes, e.g. (North,Coal plant)
    Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=21, Domain=pro_tuples_domain, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    [('Mid', 'Biomass plant'), ('Mid', 'Gas plant'), ('Mid', 'Hydro plant'), ('Mid', 'Lignite plant'), ('Mid', 'Photovoltaics'), ('Mid', 'Slack powerplant'), ('Mid', 'Wind park'), ('North', 'Biomass plant'), ('North', 'Coal plant'), ('North', 'Gas plant'), ('North', 'Hydro plant'), ('North', 'Photovoltaics'), ('North', 'Slack powerplant'), ('North', 'Wind park'), ('South', 'Biomass plant'), ('South', 'Coal plant'), ('South', 'Gas plant'), ('South', 'Hydro plant'), ('South', 'Photovoltaics'), ('South', 'Slack powerplant'), ('South', 'Wind park')]
```

e.g.:

```
m.def_process_capacity = pyomo.Constraint(
            m.pro_tuples,
            rule=def_process_capacity_rule,
            doc='total process capacity = inst-cap + new capacity')
```

Comment: Thank you, @Icedkk. In fact, I understand how to multiply two arrays to form a tuple. But maybe the tuple is not what I need, or I am not quite sure how to apply tuples to my problem. Let me raise an example. Say I have two products, apples and pears, and apples will be sold during week 1 ~ N, while pears week 2 ~ N. Then I want to assign product apples a period `T_ap = {1, 2, ..., N}`, and product pears `T_pe = {2, 3, ..., N}`. Then for each product, the operation rules are defined within their own period. Any suggestions?